# Dependent properties

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

I am new to WPF.. Can anyone tell.. What exactly the depentent properties means?..

How it differ from normal properties??? and can i edit the design page in asp 3.5 while am i running the application, because the same is possible in asp 2.0.

Comment: @Senthilkumar - Make sure to accept answers on your questions by clicking the checkmark beside the one that helped you most, it gives you and the answerer rep, flags the correct answer for the next googler that comes along with the same issue, and makes your questions much more appealing to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use a `DependencyProperty` when you want to support the setting of the property from XAML code (rather than just procedurally)

Answer (score 0):

Dependency properties depend on multiple providers for determining its value at any one point. These providers could be constantly changing its value. Dependency properties also support change notiication (as do standard properties if you implement the correct interfaces, dependency properties just make that so much easier, as they can be added with simple XAML code).