# What is dependent property in silverlight/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, dependency-properties

As the titles says. What is a dependent property in silverlight/wpf.

Comment: Where have you heard this term? In what context?

Comment: I don't even think there's such a thing, and if there is, could you give a link or article where it is used and the context of the word "dependant"?

Comment: you mean dependency property in wpf context?

Comment: @All: Hope I didn't misunderstand OP's question.

Comment: I think it must therefore be an internal term used by the current company therefore. I just assumed it sounded like something c# may have.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in C#. I guess you are talking about *dependency properties*, which are a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) concept. See [Dependent properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508085/dependent-properties) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).